# Topology of the soliton manifold unchanged by symmetry breaking potential and nonlinearity

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

For the NLS equation with a power non-linearity and no potential in $\mathbb{R}^d$
$$
i\partial_t \Psi = -\Delta \Psi + |\Psi|^{\sigma}\Psi,
$$
the soliton manifold, due to symmetries of the NLS, is $\mathcal{M} = S^1\times \mathrm{SO}(d)\times \mathbb{R}^{2d}\times \tau$ since we have translations, galilean boosts, rotations, phase invariance of $|\Psi|^{\sigma}$ and there is generally an open interval $\tau$ where solutions bifurcate from the ground state.

Consider now a more general NLS equation with a potential $V$ and a general nonlinearity $f$
$$
\partial_t \Psi = -\Delta \Psi +V(x)\Psi+ f(\Psi)\Psi
$$
such that $V$ breaks translations and rotations (perhaps into some subgroups) and an $f$ that does not have a phase symmetry (like $\ln (\Psi/\Psi^{*})$)

I was told that ("on general grounds") the topology of the Soliton manifold $\mathcal{M}$ would have to be the same as above even if $V$ and $f$ break the symmetries.

But I cannot find any reference where they discuss this topological equivalence after including these terms, since the soliton manifold would no longer be generated by the group actions.

Can someone:

1. point out some reference where they discuss why the topology remains unchanged with the inclusion of a $V$ and/or a general $f$, and
2. sketch if possible why(or why not if the statement is wrong) the topology remains the same?

Thank you for your time

**Edit:**

At this point I think that the nonmodular nonlinearity might complicate things too much since it is not very well studied so I would be satisfied with a statement about the simplified problem of having $f(\Psi) = f(|\Psi^2|)$ like $|\Psi|^{2\sigma}$  but adding a symmetry breaking potential $V$ i.e. Does

$$
\partial_t \Psi = -\Delta \Psi +V(x)\Psi+ f(|\Psi|^2)\Psi
$$

have still as its Soliton manifold $\mathcal{M} = S^1\times \mathrm{SO}(d)\times \mathbb{R}^{2d}\times \tau$ even if $SO(d)\times\mathbb{R}^{2d}$ is not generated anymore by the group actions?

[Added by DR from content of non-answer posting]

Would this be analogous to spontaneous symmetry breaking (I guess this is explicit symmetry breaking) where there is a ground state for each element of the original symmetry group $G$ i.e. $\mathcal{M} = \{g\Phi_0|g\in G\}$? and this persist? I have seen various discussions on spontaneous symmetry breaking in the NLS and they discuss the existence of asymmetric solitons thus it seems plausible to expect something analogous particularly if the potential $V$ is a small perturbation (semiclassical limit) as it should not affect radically the dimensionality of the soliton manifold, even if that small perturbation breaks most of the symmetries... but I was hoping for a serious answer with details.